# Setup apache2 WebDAV to work on user directories with correct permissions

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, webdav

I am going to give an extra access for users on the Linux box to their files through WebDav using apache2 and dav, dav_fs modules. But found that all files are created by web server owner. Is it possible to achieve my goal and be able to do following:

1) make all user's dirs accessible using their login/pass
2) make files created under current user's name and group

Is it even possible in apache? Or it's so monolithic and doesn't even care about per user WebDAV?

Any alternatives will be also appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you first question: yes, you can using [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html). This module will create new files with user/group of the apache process owner. So, the apache owner needs to be able to access all your users homedirs.

Your second question: There is a module called peruser MPM which is not production ready and has serious security implications. Also combining peruser MPM with mod_userdir is not obvious.

An alternative could be Alfresco, which has a Open Source (community) version and uses Tomcat (it's completely written in Java). Besides a Webdav server it features an smb server (windows networking) and a web interface to access/share files. Much more complicated to set up than apache + mod_userdir, though, as it's a complete document management system.

Comment: Hi @Jasper, thanks for answer. I didn't know about MPM. Alfresco will need tomcat instance always running - I would like something more light for now, although it can be a good solution for other tasks. Thanks so much.